# How to save Stream on server without dialog box in silverligh5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

i created one app, which is recording user voice from system Mic, and save file on system Harddisk using dialog box, which is working fine !

but my requirement is, i want to save Stream on server **without dialog box**

this is what i tried so far:-

```
 private SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog()
 { 
   Filter = "Audio files(*.wav)|*.wav"
};

        protected void SaveFile()
        {
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == false)
            {
                return;
            }

            StatusText = "Saving...";

            Stream stream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();

            WavManager.SavePcmToWav(_sink.BackingStream, stream, _sink.CurrentFormat);

            stream.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Your record is saved.");

            GoToStartState();
        }



public class WavManager
    {
        public static void SavePcmToWav(Stream rawData, Stream output, AudioFormat audioFormat)
        {
            if (audioFormat.WaveFormat != WaveFormatType.Pcm)
                throw new ArgumentException("Only PCM coding is supported.");

            BinaryWriter bwOutput = new BinaryWriter(output);

            // Write down the WAV header.
            // Refer to http://technology.niagarac.on.ca/courses/ctec1631/WavFileFormat.html
            // for details on the format.

            // Note that we use ToCharArray() when writing fixed strings
            // to force using the char[] overload because
            // Write(string) writes the string prefixed by its length.

            // -- RIFF chunk

            bwOutput.Write("RIFF".ToCharArray());

            // Total Length Of Package To Follow
            // Computed as data length plus the header length without the data
            // we have written so far and this data (44 - 4 ("RIFF") - 4 (this data))
            bwOutput.Write((uint)(rawData.Length + 36));

            bwOutput.Write("WAVE".ToCharArray());

            // -- FORMAT chunk

            bwOutput.Write("fmt ".ToCharArray());

            // Length Of FORMAT Chunk (Binary, always 0x10)
            bwOutput.Write((uint)0x10);

            // Always 0x01
            bwOutput.Write((ushort)0x01);

            // Channel Numbers (Always 0x01=Mono, 0x02=Stereo)
            bwOutput.Write((ushort)audioFormat.Channels);

            // Sample Rate (Binary, in Hz)
            bwOutput.Write((uint)audioFormat.SamplesPerSecond);

            // Bytes Per Second
            bwOutput.Write((uint)(audioFormat.BitsPerSample * audioFormat.SamplesPerSecond * audioFormat.Channels / 8));

            // Bytes Per Sample: 1=8 bit Mono, 2=8 bit Stereo or 16 bit Mono, 4=16 bit Stereo
            bwOutput.Write((ushort)(audioFormat.BitsPerSample * audioFormat.Channels / 8));

            // Bits Per Sample
            bwOutput.Write((ushort)audioFormat.BitsPerSample);

            // -- DATA chunk

            bwOutput.Write("data".ToCharArray());

            // Length Of Data To Follow
            bwOutput.Write((uint)rawData.Length);

            // Raw PCM data follows...

            // Reset position in rawData and remember its origin position
            // to restore at the end.
            long originalRawDataStreamPosition = rawData.Position;
            rawData.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Append all data from rawData stream into output stream.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read;       // number of bytes read in one iteration
            while ((read = rawData.Read(buffer, 0, 4096)) > 0)
            {
                bwOutput.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            rawData.Seek(originalRawDataStreamPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a dialog, you should have a constant string which contains the location to where the stream should be saved. Best practice is to keep this in the web.config of the server, so you can change the path at any moment.

Comment: What you have tried so far...post your code for more clarity of your question...also read http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/opening-doc-file-clientside-without-103393.aspx for your help...

Comment: Have you tried using a filestream?

Comment: @djerry, what's relation between file stream and save dialog box? all i want that, i wanted to skip dialog box!

Comment: When you use a save dialog box, you get the stream to save from the method "OpenFile". When you use a filestream/filewriter, you have to create your own stream.